# closing sqlite in listview database with onclick method

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

first of all I am new developer of android i am learing so please bear with me.
I am making a app related to book chapters and displaying its content, I got working listview populated from database, but facing some bugs
:-

1. on leaving application i am having force close see log cat.
2. in list view i am getting new data being appended in database. I want it to be one time only. as chapter names will be constant for a book
3. on chapter click, selected chapter list should open.

please let me know how to correct them

**mainactivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DBADChapter myDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        openDB();
        registerListClickCallback();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        closeDB();
        myDb.deleteAll();
    }

    private void openDB() {
        myDb = new DBADChapter(this);
        myDb.open();
        myDb.insertRow(999, "TITLE 1");
        myDb.insertRow(991, "TITLE 2");
        myDb.insertRow(992, "TITLE 3");
        myDb.insertRow(993, "TITLE 4");
        populatelistviewfromDB();
    }

    private void closeDB() {
        myDb.close();
        myDb.deleteAll();

    }

    public void onClick_AddRecord(View v) {

    }

    private void populatelistviewfromDB() {
        Cursor cursor = myDb.getAllRows();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] { DBADChapter.KEY_CHEPTERNUM,
                DBADChapter.KEY_CHAPTERHEADING };
        int[] toViewIds = new int[] { R.id.tvchapterno, R.id.tvchapter };
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.item_view, cursor, fromFieldNames, toViewIds);

        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listchapter);
        myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);

    }

    private void registerListClickCallback() {

        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listchapter);
        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,
                    int position, long idInDB) {

                Cursor cursor = myDb.getRow(idInDB);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                }
                cursor.close();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        closeDB();
        myDb.deleteAll();
    }

}
```

**Database**

```
public class DBADChapter2 {

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;

    public static final String KEY_CHEPTERNUM = "chapternum";
    public static final String KEY_CHAPTERHEADING = "chapterheading";

    public static final int COL_CHEPTERNUM = 1;
    public static final int COL_CHAPTERHEADING = 2;

    public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_CHEPTERNUM, KEY_CHAPTERHEADING };

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDb";
    public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "chapters";

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = "create table "
            + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" + KEY_ROWID
            + " integer primary key autoincrement, "

            + KEY_CHEPTERNUM + " integer not null, " + KEY_CHAPTERHEADING
            + " string not null"

            + ");";

    private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelperChapter myDBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBADChapter2(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelperChapter(context);
    }

    public DBADChapter2 open() {
        db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        myDBHelper.close();
    }

    public long insertRow(int number, String chapterheadings) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_CHEPTERNUM, number);
        initialValues.put(KEY_CHAPTERHEADING, chapterheadings);

        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
    }

    public void deleteAll() {
        Cursor c = getAllRows();
        long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        c.close();
    }

    public Cursor getAllRows() {
        String where = null;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
        String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
        Cursor c = db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
        }
        return c;
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelperChapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelperChapter(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
            _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version "
                    + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion
                    + ", which will destroy all old data!");

            _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

            onCreate(_db);
        }
    }
}
```

logcat

```
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.bookz.bookz1/com.bookz.bookz1.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2354)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2291)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:942)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: database not open
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1230)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1189)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at com.bookz.bookz1.DBADChapter.getAllRows(DBADChapter.java:130)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at com.bookz.bookz1.DBADChapter.deleteAll(DBADChapter.java:117)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at com.bookz.bookz1.MainActivity.closeDB(MainActivity.java:53)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at com.bookz.bookz1.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:79)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3851)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1191)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:2341)
10-06 18:52:30.822: E/AndroidRuntime(564):  ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 1):

In your onPause() method you say:

```
     super.onPause();
    closeDB();
    myDb.deleteAll();
```

And also your closeDB() does the following thing:

```
     myDb.close();
    myDb.deleteAll();
```

So one of the errors in your code is that you call deleteAll() twice for no reason.

Second,  why would you call closeDB and then deleteAll afterwards? Simple logic says that you close your DataBase once you've finished all work with it. You log cat says the error is "database not open"  so you've obviously closed your database but your trying to do more work with it.

**Try switching places of deleteAll and close, that should fix the problem.**

Comment: thanks janbo let me know how to stop apending new data in database

Comment: never mind i deleted on destroy code and updated order. now i get only one entry all time